# How do I dispose the value of StreamProvider in Flutter when a user log outs?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-provider

I have an app where I use StreamProvider to fetch data from Firestore & pass it around in the app. While it works as I want, the problem arises when I log out & sign in again from a different user ID, it still shows the data from the first user. What do I do to make sure the StreamProvider disposes the current value when a user logs out, and refetches the proper user data when a new user signs in? Here's my code

main.dart

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final db = Database();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthenticationService>(
          create: (_) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
        //  key: ObjectKey(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid),
          create: (context) =>
              context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<AppointmentProvider>(
          create: (_) => AppointmentProvider(),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
          catchError: (context, error) {
            print(error);
          },
          create: (BuildContext context) => db.getAppointments(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        key: GlobalObjectKey(context),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Hospital App',
        theme: appTheme,
        home: AuthenticationWrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

db.getAppointments() method

```
 Stream<List<AppointmentModel>> getAppointments() {
    return _firebaseFirestore
        .collection("DoctorAppointments")
        .doc(uid)
        .collection("DoctorAppointmentsList")
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapShot) => snapShot.docs
            .map((document) => AppointmentModel.fromJson(document.data()))
            .toList());
  }
```

Comment: did you fix this?